# Chrome Extension TypeError : uncaught TypeError, cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

I'm building a chrome extension using typescript and webpack and started experiencing a few errors after introducing a recently release node module into my project.

The module I installed: https://github.com/gregtuc/StockSocket

The error appears in the browser when I load my extension

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
```

Stack Trace

```
contentscript.js:35159 (./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserFetcher.js)
contentscript.js:83680 (__webpack_require__)
contentscript.js:36432 (./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/Puppeteer.js)
contentscript.js:83680 (__webpack_require__)
contentscript.js:34971 (./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/initialize-node.js)
contentscript.js:83680 (__webpack_require__)
contentscript.js:35022 (./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node.js)
contentscript.js:83680 (__webpack_require__)
contentscript.js:24201 (./node_modules/puppeteer/cjs-entry.js)
contentscript.js:83680 (__webpack_require__)
contentscript.js:67322 (./node_modules/stocksocket/stocksocket.js)
contentscript.js:83680 (__webpack_require__)
contentscript.js:83765 (anonymous function)
contentscript.js:83792 (anonymous function)
contentscript.js:83794 (anonymous function)
```

```
...

const readdirAsync = util_1.promisify(fs.readdir.bind(fs));
const mkdirAsync = util_1.promisify(fs.mkdir.bind(fs));
const unlinkAsync = util_1.promisify(fs.unlink.bind(fs));
const chmodAsync = util_1.promisify(fs.chmod.bind(fs));
function existsAsync(filePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        fs.access(filePath, (err) => resolve(!err));
    });
}

...
```

This is my webpack config file

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const { resolve } = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const tsRule = {
    test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: 'ts-loader',
};

const plugins = [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/popup-page/popup.html',
        filename: 'popup.html',
        chunks: ['popup'],
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [{ from: 'public', to: '.' }],
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        process: 'process/browser',
        Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
    }),
];

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
            util: require.resolve('util/'),
            fs: false,
            stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
            constants: require.resolve('constants-browserify'),
            assert: require.resolve('assert/'),
            url: require.resolve('url/'),
            net: false,
            tls: false,
            https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
            http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
            os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
            zlib: require.resolve('browserify-zlib'),
            child_process: false,
        },
    },
    entry: {
        popup: './src/popup-page/popup.tsx',
        contentscript: './src/contentscript.tsx',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [tsRule],
    },
    plugins,
};
```

this is my ts config

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */,
        "module": "es6" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */,
        "jsx": "react" /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', 'react', 'react-jsx' or 'react-jsxdev'. */,
        "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
        "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */,
        "typeRoots": [
            "./types",
            "./node_modules/@types"
        ] /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */,
        "types": [
            "node"
        ] /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */,
        "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
        "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "typings"]
}
```

And my contentscript.tsx file

```
import React, { FC, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import * as CSS from 'csstype';
import StockSocket from 'stocksocket';

interface Props {}

const divBar = document.createElement('div');
divBar.className = 'mini-ticker-extension';
divBar.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
divBar.style.position = 'sticky';
divBar.style.zIndex = '100000';
divBar.style.height = '50px';
divBar.style.top = '0';

export const TickerBar: FC<Props> = () => {
    interface TickerHash {}

    const [tickers, setTickers] = useState<TickerHash>();

    const tickerStyle: CSS.Properties = {
        padding: 0,
    };

    const stockPriceChanged = (data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
    };

    StockSocket.addTickers(['TSLA', 'NIO', 'NNDM', 'ETH-USD'], stockPriceChanged);

    return <p style={tickerStyle}>hello world</p>;
};

render(<TickerBar />, divBar);

document.querySelector('body')?.prepend(divBar);
```

Earlier I was getting webpack errors where 'fs', 'child-process', or 'path' were not able to resolve when compiling. The solution I found said to include the fallbacks in the module exports. After including them, I had another error in my browser where 'process' and 'Buffer' could not be resolved, so I found another solution that led me to require it in my webpack config in the plugins array.  I'm not sure if the way I went about those solutions were correct, and if they may be contributing to this new error.  If someone could explain these errors to me I would appreciate it very much.

Link to my repo: https://github.com/bryanmoon1991/mini-ticker-extension

I'm trying to build an extension that places a small bar at the top of your current webpage that displays stock ticker information so that you can keep an eye on selected tickers while continuing to browse.

I am a beginner developer and this is my first time working with webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module you have chosen, StockSocket, is meant to be used in a Node.js environment and not a web browser. The errors with ‘fs’, ‘childprocess’, etc arise because StockSocket itself (of one of its dependencies) use these modules which are builtin in Node and not the browser.

Looking at the source code briefly for StockSocket, it uses [puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer) which is a node.js library for controlling a headless webbrowser. This makes StockSocket a poor fit for a browser extension. I’d have a look at the source code for StockSocket and see if you can replicate some of the behavior using browser APIs!

Comment: That makes sense, thanks so much for the clarification!  I will try out your suggestion, do you think a better approach for my extension would be to use websockets in order to grab the data I need in real time?